# Stripe createPaymentMethod doesnt return any errors

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

```
return await stripe
          .createPaymentMethod({
            type: 'card',
            card: cardElement,
            billing_details: {
              name: fullName,
              email: email!,
              phone: mobile!,
            },
          })
          .then(({ paymentMethod, error }) => {
            console.log(paymentMethod, error);
          })
          .catch(e => {
            throw e;
          });
```

I cant get createPaymentMethod to return any error messages using any of the test cards from stripe doco - not sure whether I'm doing something wrong - any help is appreciated

4000000000000002

4000000000000127

Answer (score 0):

It is not expected for `createPaymentMethod` to return those test card declines for structurally valid card details. If you entered data that cannot be valid, you could get an error. For example 2-digit CVC would get `incomplete_cvc` or an expiry date in the past would get `invalid_expiry_year_past`.

To get the decline errors, you need to use the created payment method to confirm a payment intent or setup intent, or try attaching the payment method to a customer.